# Shell+java error

Tags: shell, java, sh

I want to run either editor.sh or snippetCollector.sh under modules/editor/scripts in Sentrick. So I got it by `git clone git://sentrick.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/sentrick/sentrick`. That is not a problem. I read the documentation under the doc folder. It says to run either editor.sh or snippetCollector.sh. I go and I do:  `./editor.sh` and it doesn't work. So I see online that you can also use `sh editor.sh` which also doesn't work. It says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/denkselbst/sentrick/sbeditor/SbEditor
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.denkselbst.sentrick.sbeditor.SbEditor
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: de.denkselbst.sentrick.sbeditor.SbEditor.  Program will exit.
```

I have not edited anything so I think that it should work, but it doesn't!!

Inside `editor.sh` (the one I want to run but can't) it says only this:

```
java -cp @CP.UNIX@ de.denkselbst.sentrick.sbeditor.SbEditor
```

The problem with snippetCollector.sh is the same

Comment: in which environment you test it is it UNIX ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-cp` is configuring the CLASSPATH, which should contain a reference to the directory containing your classes. I suspect that's not been set correctly, and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) is a useful reference for setting it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing some class files while running your code..please check whether you follow all the steps mentioned in your doc..make sure to set the CLASSPATH and try to rerun the program..

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you are having class path issue. Normaly when I run application in linux envirenment my sh is look like bellow.

```
#!/bin/sh

THE_CLASSPATH=/home/pathto/lib

java -cp ${THE_CLASSPATH}/required.jar de.denkselbst.sentrick.sbeditor.SbEditor
```